# What do the "bisect" and "heapselect" tools in Crossfilter do?

Tags: javascript, crossfilter

In the [Crossfilter API reference](https://github.com/square/crossfilter/wiki/API-Reference), `bisect` is described as

> The identity bisector; suitable for numbers, dates, strings, and other naturally-comparable objects.`

`heapselect` is described as

> The identity heapselect function; suitable for numbers, dates, strings, and other naturally-comparable objects.

But what do they do, and how are they used?

Answer (score 4):

`bisect` lets you split a sorted array into two parts. Think of it like a page fell out of a book. If you want to put that page back in, you need to split the book where the left part is pages with numbers less than your page number, and the right part is pages with numbers greater than your page number.

`heapselect` lets you get the top k elements from an array, optionally within a subset of the given array, if the array satisfies all properties of a heap. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap

In both cases, the identity function just returns all of your data back. So the identity bisector will bisect by whichever dimension you give it. The identity heapselect will heap by and heapselect by whichever dimension you give it.

Does this help?

Comment: In what scenario would one prefer one vs. the other? I am a bit confused when trying to sort out examples of use cases where I would opt for utilizing the heap function.